# top border not showing in middle div when i have 3 divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i am working on new project using html , css , bootstrap. I have a problem.
i have made a box that has border all around it and when I hover on this box an image appear inside in box ;by default inside of box is white . when I copy that box code and paste it under it first box and do it again it shows me 3 div that is exactly what I want but I have a problem my middle box's top border does not shown. what can i do??

this is one of my boxes code

```
<div>
   <a class="text-decoration-none" href="">
      <div class="po-relative mb-2">
         <img src="images/lukas-blazek-GnvurwJsKaY-unsplash.jpg" alt=""class="img-fluid">
         <div class="po-absolute">
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

and this is all the css's related to these boxes

```
.po-relative {
    position: relative;
    border: .5px solid #cecece;
}

.po-absolute {
    background-color: white;
    height: 176px;
    width: 266px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.po-absolute:hover {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 20%;
}
```

and also I post an image about my problem
[image: my problem]

Comment: Set some margins, looks like they are overlapping.

Comment: already done this but it does'nt help me . thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is, you have set your width and height in a box of position absolute, which does not affect the width and height of the parent, as a result is being cut off.

I moved the width and height to the position relative, and set the left,top,bottom on the position absolute element.

Here you go.

```css
.po-relative {
    position: relative;
    border: .5px solid #cecece;
    height: 176px;
    width: 266px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.po-absolute {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0 left:0 right:0 transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.po-absolute:hover {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a class="text-decoration-none" href="">
      <div class="po-relative mb-2">
         <img src="images/lukas-blazek-GnvurwJsKaY-unsplash.jpg" alt=""class="img-fluid">
         <div class="po-absolute">
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="text-decoration-none" href="">
      <div class="po-relative mb-2">
         <img src="images/lukas-blazek-GnvurwJsKaY-unsplash.jpg" alt=""class="img-fluid">
         <div class="po-absolute">
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="text-decoration-none" href="">
      <div class="po-relative mb-2">
         <img src="images/lukas-blazek-GnvurwJsKaY-unsplash.jpg" alt=""class="img-fluid">
         <div class="po-absolute">
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```